# Processing a script of type="text/template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form which is a within a `<script type="text/template>`. I have done this as I have a form which has dynamic fields and row numbering. Everything works fine however I am unable to submit that form data using php. I have wrapped the script in a form tag ad have placed a submit button, but no value is passed into the second script. How could I retrieve the values from this template?

```
<form id="frm" method="post" action="../book2.php">
  <script type="text/template" id="categoryTemplate">
    <div class="category" id="category{{ID}}"> 
      <div class="container-fluid">          
        <h4 style="display:inline; text-align:left">Person {{ID}}</h4>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
            <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="fname" class="control-label">First&nbsp;Name</label>
            <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="fname"  placeholder="First Name" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="sname" class="control-label">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Surname" >
          </div>

       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
   </script>
   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: _"have a form which is a within a <script type="text/template>. "_ `script` appear to be within `form` element . What is expected result ?

Comment: what is the reason for putting script in there? From my perspective, you don't even need the script. And it doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

Comment: @guest271314 ahh sorry, wrong way round... have a <script type="text/template>  which is a within a form. I want to be able to post the form to another php script

Comment: @TreeNguyen I have used a script because I wanted to create a clone template. I have a button that will clone this form and insert it as a row under the first row. The scrip allows me to also number each row uniquely.

Comment: @John if that's the case, my suggestion is moving this one to jQuery to create the form. Having it here might make your code a bit messy :). Look at Flosculus answer :)